# How can I print the Canonical String which aws-requests-auth sends?

Tags: amazon-web-services, authentication, boto3, amazon-sagemaker

I want to have a lambda calling a Sagemaker instance in another region. If both are in the same region, everything works fine. If they are not, I get the following error:

```
The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your AWS Secret Access Key and signing method. Consult the service documentation for details.

The Canonical String for this request should have been
'POST
/endpoints/foo-endpoint/invocations

host:runtime.sagemaker.us-east-1.amazonaws.com
x-amz-date:20180406T082536Z

host;x-amz-date
1234567890foobarfoobarfoobarboofoobarfoobarfoobarfoobarfoobarfoo'

The String-to-Sign should have been
'AWS4-HMAC-SHA256
20180406T082536Z
20180406/us-east-1/sagemaker/aws4_request
987654321abcdeffoobarfoobarfoobarfoobarfoobarfoobarfoobarfoobarf'
```

I use [`aws-requests-auth`](https://github.com/DavidMuller/aws-requests-auth) (0.4.1) with boto3 (1.5.15 - updating to 1.7.1 didn't change anything, [changelog](https://github.com/boto/boto3/blob/develop/CHANGELOG.rst)) like this:

```
import requests
from aws_requests_auth.aws_auth import AWSRequestsAuth
auth = AWSRequestsAuth(aws_access_key=config['AWS']['ACCESS_KEY'],
                       aws_secret_access_key=(
                           config['AWS']['SECRET_ACCESS_KEY']),
                       aws_host=config['AWS']['HOST'],
                       aws_region=config['AWS']['REGION'],
                       aws_service=config['AWS']['SERVICE'])

payload = {'foo': 'bar'}
response = requests.post(post_url,
                         data=json.dumps(payload),
                         headers={'content-type': 'application/json'},
                         auth=auth)
```

printing `auth` only gives `<aws_requests_auth.aws_auth.AWSRequestsAuth object at 0x7f9d00c98390>`.

Is there a way to print the "Canonical String" mentioned in the error message?

(Any other ideas how to fix this are appreciated as well)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A work-around for the asked question:

```
req = requests.request('POST', 'http://httpbin.org/get')
req.body = b''
req.method = ''
print(auth.get_aws_request_headers(req,
                                   aws_access_key=auth.aws_access_key,
                                   aws_secret_access_key=auth.aws_secret_access_key,
                                   aws_token=auth.aws_token))
```

The problem is not solved, though. And now I wonder what the first argument of `auth.get_aws_request_headers` is.

Comment: I finally just made all AWS stuff run in the same region. Saves you from headaches.

Comment: fyi, the first arg is https://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/api/#requests.Request. Essentially, you don't have to trigger the request but prepare it instead.